# Обновления приожения ios

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

В апсторе есть приложение которое разрабатывалось с учетом ios6, нижняя планка была ios5.Теперь я хочу сделать в пятом xcode версию для ios7 (обновленье). Но собранный мной вариант выглядит нормально в семерке,но на шестой версии оси там проблемы а автолэяутом. Гарантирует ли что что я собрал это обновление в пятом xcode что владельцам семерки придет обновление а владельцам шестерки нет(это то что мне нужно)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках XCode можно поставить минимальную версию iOS. Тогда обновление прийдёт тем людям, у которых стоит нужная Вам iOS.